# Python web scraping/ data extraction

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webautomation

For my master thesis, I am exploring the possibility to extract data from a website via web automation.  The steps are as follows:

1. Sign in to the website ( https://www.metal.com/Copper/201102250376 )
2. Input username and password
3. Click sign-in
4. Change date to 01/01/2020
5. Scrape the table data generated and then save it to csv file
6. Save to a specific folder with a specific name on my PC
7. Run the same sequence to download additional historical price data  for other materials in a new tab in the same browser window

**I am stuck in steps 5, 6 and 7**

from selenium import webdriver

DRIVER_PATH = 'C:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=ChromeOptions)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.metal.com/Copper/201102250376')

#Login steps
LoginClick1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
'#__next > div > div.smm-component-header-en > div.main > div.right > button.button.sign-in')

LoginClick1.click()

user_input = driver.find_element_by_id('user_name')
user_input.send_keys('#####')

password_input = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
password_input.send_keys('####')

Submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
'body > div:nth-child(17) > div > div.ant-modal-wrap.ant-modal-centered.smm-component-sign-en > div > div.ant-modal-content > div > div > div > div.smm-component-sign-en-content > form > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > span > button')

Submit.click()

time.sleep(2)

#scroll down the point of interest in page
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,1000)", "")

#change currency
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//img[contains(@class,'icon___BUqam')]").click()

time.sleep(1)

#change date from datepicker

date_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
'//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[5]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWVII.png)/div[7]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWVII.png)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piOG3.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWVII.png)/span[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWVII.png)/div/i')

date_input.click()

action = ActionChains(driver)

action.move_to_element(date_input).send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE).send_keys(
Keys.BACKSPACE).send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE).send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE).send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE).send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE).send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE).send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE).send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE).send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE).perform()

action.move_to_element(date_input).send_keys("01/01/2020").perform()
action.move_to_element(date_input).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()

time.sleep(2)

I am stuck trying to scrape the data from the table generated and then save into a csv file using selenium. See HTML code below
[table generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWVII.png)

**May 27, 2022**
**10,758.75-10,788.43**
**10,773.59**
**+97.94**
**USD/mt**

Any help would be massively appreciated.

> Download file using button press
> [Download button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piOG3.png)

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//img[contains(@src,'https://static.metal.com/www.metal.com/4.1.161/static/images/price/download.png')]").click()

time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//img[contains(@src,'https://static.metal.com/www.metal.com/4.1.161/static/images/price/download_excel.png')]").click()
```

To save time since I have multiple files/data to download, I am also exploring the possibility of directly saving the file via the download button provided.

- **The problem I encounter** is that I am not able to directly specify the filename I want it to be saved as.
- Upon click, the download button opens a new tab and then closes
  within seconds to initialize the file download.
- The file is then downloaded with a *materialcode-today's date* file
  naming format.

Have you any idea on how to go about this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `sign in` button is not getting clicked is because the xpath `//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]` is incorrect the `id` of `next` is the main container `div` through which we are naviagting to the `sign button` by providing remaining html nodre structure

Instead you can directly select the sign in button as `//button[@class='button sign-in']` based on its class value [image: Refer Image attached]

Your solution for sign in would look like

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.metal.com/Nickel/201102250239')
# Click on Sign In
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='button sign-in']").click()
# Enter username
driver.find_element(By.ID, "user_name").send_keys("your username")
# Enter password
driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys("your password") 
# Click Sign In
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

`To scrape data`

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("historyBodyRow___1Bk9u"):
 elements =element.find_elements_by_tag_name("div")
 print("Date="+ elements[0].text)
 print("Price Range="+ elements[1].text)
 print("Avg="+ elements[2].text)
 print("Change="+ elements[3].text)
 print("Unit="+ elements[4].text)
```

`Add To CSV`

```
import csv
f = open('Path where you want to store the file', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)
for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("historyBodyRow___1Bk9u"):
  elements =element.find_elements_by_tag_name("div")
  entry = [elements[0].text ,elements[1].text ,elements[2].text , elements[3].text, elements[4].text]
  writer.writerow(entry)
```

f.close

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, I encountered a new problem trying to scrape the generated table data. I do not know how to go about it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72399631/14434657

Comment: Here's the HTML code: 

<div class="historyBodyRow___1Bk9u"><div class="" style="padding-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%; width: auto; text-align: left;">May 27, 2022</div><div class="" style="padding-left: 6px; width: 30%; text-align: right;">10,758.75-10,788.43</div><div class="" style="padding-left: 6px; width: 20%; text-align: right;">10,773.59</div><div class="up___11LCm" style="padding-left: 6px; width: 20%; text-align: right;">+97.94</div><div class="" style="padding-left: 6px; width: 15%; text-align: right;">USD/mt</div></div>

Comment: Hi @Esclass  in order to scrape data you will have to loop through all div having class historyBodyRow___1Bk9u

Comment: Your solution would look like https://stackoverflow.com/a/72413918/18132195 Refer `Scrape Data` section

Comment: To stroe data into csv you can use the CSV library. Refer https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-write-csv-file/

Comment: @Esclass you can use the csv library fir that . A basic solution would look like https://stackoverflow.com/a/72413918/18132195 Refer Add to CSV section

Comment: Thanks! That worked :)  @Darshan Shah
Kindly also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/72399631/14434657,  - download file with button click section - could you help me with that?

Comment: Hi @Esclass to download the file it requires an account so I can't check the actual behaviour for that

Comment: You are right. I could have shared my login details but it is company related, hence I can't. Thanks for all the assistance.